# Как внутри объекта, динамически изменять одни его свойства, изменяя другие? Т.е. как создать зависимость?

Tags: javascript

Логически пытался сделать как-то так, но это неправильно:

```
var foo = {
  lol: 5,
  kek: this.lol+3
}

alert (foo.kek);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помошью [геттера](https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters#ukazanie-get-set-v-literalah)

```js
var foo = {
  lol: 5,
  get kek(){ return this.lol+3 }
}
console.log(foo.kek);
```

Answer (score 4):

Для решения этой задачи вы можете использовать `функцию сеттер` для свойства у которого вы хотите переопределить операцию присваивания.

Ниже я привёл простой пример решения вашей задачи, так как здесь не рассмотрен вопрос инкапсуляции свойства `_name` - то есть запрет на изменения этого свойства напрямую `human._name = ''` минуя сеттер и соответственно валидацию на минимальное количество символов:

```js
let human = {
  _name: 'Не задано', // переменная для хранения значения свойства name
  name_length: 0, // переменная которую мы будем изменять при изменении свойства name
  
  set name(new_val) {
    if (new_val.length === 0) { // делаем валидацию
        // выходим из функции, после этого код функции дальше
        // не будет выполнятся, и присвоение неправильного значения
        // не произойдёт
     return;
    }
    
    // выполняем сохранение значения для текущего свойства
    this._name = new_val;

    // меняем другое свойство объекта
    this.name_length = new_val.length;
  },
  get name() {
    // возвращаем значение свойства name
    return this._name;
  }
}



alert(`Имя [${human.name}], Количество символов [${human.name_length}]`);

human.name = ''; // присвоение не произойдёт так как значение не валидно
alert(`Имя [${human.name}], Количество символов [${human.name_length}]`);

human.name = 'Алексей'; // присвоение успешно
alert(`Имя [${human.name}], Количество символов [${human.name_length}]`);
```

То есть, когда вы будете присваивать значение переменной `human.name` в этот момент вызовется функция в которой вы сами определяете какие операции выполнять, соответственно в этот момент вы можете присвоить значение другому свойству вашего объекта или же произвести другие операции.

Подробнее о [сеттерах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) и [геттерах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Comment: Отличный ответ!